# is there a way to have domain name for private address in virtual private network in azure?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-dns, azure-private-dns-zone

I'm using azure portal, created a virtual private network and virtual machines in it. so, in order to access the web page from the vm's which are in private network I'll be using vpn client on my laptop. so far good but instead of giving private IP and accessing from the browser is there any to have a domain name and access it while I connected to the virtual network using vpn client?

I already came across windows hosts on my laptop machine but apart from that is there any solution which is from azure itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom DNS server in that Azure VNet and add it to the `DNS server` of that VNet as the steps [here](https://masterandcmdr.com/2016/10/21/azure-point-2-site-vpn-dns-config-is-wrong/), then re-download your VPN clients package to take the update effect on your networking.

You could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64792291/active-directory-domain-controller-cant-be-resolved-on-local-machine-through-po/64799643#64799643) for your DNS configuration but you don't need to deploy an ADDC in this case. For more information, you could read [Name resolution that uses your own DNS server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances#name-resolution-that-uses-your-own-dns-server).